# My Flutter ProjectName Showing reminder after Upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart

2 months ago, I create a project with PascalCase named and it is fine, there is no problem with my project. And now, after I upgrade at flutter stable 2.0.0. The name of my package has a reminder like this

> Use `lowercase_with_underscores` for package names

what should I do? Is there a solution without downgrade the flutter sdk or changing my Package Name?

thanks in advance..

Comment: Without downgrade you can exclude this warning by linter exclude https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/file_names.html. Disabling the linter refer the https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/file_names.html'

Comment: can you give me an example I have opened that link but I don't know how to use the lints at my package name. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flutter & dart stranded you must to use the package name must in lower case.

1. By Using the linter you can disable or ignore the warning
2. Refer the warning data : https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/file_names.html.
3. How to disable the warning:  https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#disabling-individual-rules

I hope it will help you.

Comment: hello. where I have to write the `linter:
  rules:
    avoid_shadowing_type_parameters: false
    await_only_futures: true` ?